# Using python 3.7 and installed pygame through pip3 but atom editor wont run pygame

Tags: python, pygame, atom-editor, python-3.7

I am super super new to all of this python and programming in general. I am on a macbook pro with the latest OS and have python 3.7 working. pygame is installed because the idle will run a game or open a window for a game that i found on the internet. but atom doesnt. please help! i want to use atom and not the standard idle. thanks!! ia have picturs but it wont let me post them

Comment: this is what atom does when i run it. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/granttarbell/Desktop/Untitled.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work but it's worth giving it a try. Open terminal and navigate to the folder where you file is using the command:

```
cd /somepath
```

Then use the command:

```
python3.7 filename.py
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This probably works, but OP wants a solution within Atom if possible.

Comment: when i paste the first one,it says it does not recognize somepath :((( i somehow got pygane to import succesfully tho. i just installed it in a billion different ways hehe